# Finding embedded flash-contents from HTML files in iOS

Tags: ios, flash, uiwebview

Am developing an application which supports viewing only HTML5 contents, certain times i am also coming across certain pages that have embedded flash contents SWF type files in it.

It shows that flash files are not supported in iOS webview.

is there anyway possible to find embedded flash-contents from HTML files?

or is it possible to show an alternative image where Flash is not supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to see the content of the html and see how they are embedding the flash content and create a javascript that you inject in the page after loading. This JS will parse the page and return true or false and you can use this to show the alert

UIWebView has an API to inject and run your own JS inside the page